# Are there any talking dragons in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, dragons

Charlie Weasley had some success in his attempts to train dragons (or at least Ron claimed as much).

But does the history of the Potterverse detail any dragon with an ability to talk to people, or to communicate with people in any other way?

Comment: Perhaps my English is not good enough for this subject. I don't refer to training as a way of communication. For me it's rather a way how Charlie gets to know something about dragons' nature. But in this particular case I'm more interested in talking dragons, not Charlie's trainings. The matter of talking dragons came to my mind after discussion in this thread: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/what-is-the-background-for-the-phrase-literary-trend-for-shit-books-about-talki I've added this sentence as the only background fact I know about.

Comment: Depends who you ask. I'm sure Hagrid would consider the many burns, bites, and scratches he got courtesy of Norbert to be clear signs that Norbert was communicating with his mummy.

Comment: We can train dogs, but they can't talk...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ron relays to Harry in *Philosopher's Stone*, ‘You can’t tame dragons, it’s dangerous. You should see the burns Charlie’s got off wild ones in Romania.’ So I'm not convinced Charlie had any success training a dragon, although he certainly does work with them.

*Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them* lists ten breeds of dragons, none of which are described as having the ability to talk.

Dragons that are aggressive toward humans are perhaps showing a rudimentary kind of communication when they attack; but on the other hand, a dragon's aggression might merely be primal. The book *Dragon Species of Great Britain and Ireland; From Egg to Inferno, A Dragon Keeper’s Guide* might shed some light on this, but we don't know what's in this book.

Hagrid, naturally, believed he could communicate with Norbert the Norwegian Ridgeback, but Hagrid probably had a different concept of what constitutes ‘communication' between humans and ‘interestin' creatures'.

**As far as I can find, there is no canon reference to dragons that ultimately end up talking or communicating with humans in a meaningful way.**

The only *possible* exception to this, I think, would be the possibility that when a wand with a dragon heartstring core chooses a wizard, perhaps the connection the wand and wizard shares is a form of communication: ‘The wand chooses the wizard.’ Mr Ollivander says in *Philosopher's Stone* that no two dragons are exactly alike, just as no two phoenixes or unicorns are.

Comment: Definitely no rush -- other people might have better answers :)

Answer (score 1):

If dating back and the past Potterverse history reflected that of Merlin during King Arthur's court, then there may be the possibility that talking dragons did exist.

Answer (score -7):

I have canonical PROOF that the dragons in the Harry Potter universe, dragons can speak English to humans (or at least wizarding humans)

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (part 2)* when they are busting out of Gringott's bank on the back of the iron belly, right before the dragon flies up and crashes through the ceiling of the lobby, and out into the world. I'd say, a good 15-20 seconds before he breaks the glass ceiling with Potter and company if you listen carefully as the Iron Belly dragon rears his head (and immediately before he flies upward and through the glass ceiling of Gringott's) he says in a very low and lulled tone,

> "THANK YOU"

Personally I am assuming that any event found in any one of the Harry Potter films is considered to be concrete fact, and hence, canonical.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you have proof that dragons in Harry Potter can talk, please kindly share it now, or your answer will get deleted.

Comment: While the dragon definitely makes a lot of noises, none of them sound like actual words to me. I think you're mistaken, and possibly hearing words where there are none because you want to hear them.

Comment: I've listened to it repeatedly and I can't hear anything that sounds like "thank you". There's nothing in the script or the book, either

Comment: It definitely does say thank you. I watched the DVD again this morning just to check and make sure again, and I also have the movie on my DVR from the Harry Potter marathons they constantly play on FREEFORM (by the way thank god they finally played OOTP... Still can't understand why they never played it in any of the other marathons ) ... But yes, once again, the dragon absolutely says thank you. I swear by it. I checked and rechecked, it isn't hard to make out, you only need turn the volume up a slight amount more than your usual preference. you can hear it clear as day.

Comment: And you can give me negative feedback all you want to. I assure you it's there. Anybody who doesn't hear it is either in denial, or just flat out has a different copy than the one that I've seen, which would be REALLY odd considering that I've heard it now on two separate platforms and one of which I do not own, so I could not have possibly altered it in any way for my own personal benefit. I'm sorry for causing angered tempers here but this IS fact. I wish I knew how to take a clip from the movie on my phone and post it here for you all to see and hear..

Comment: In the YouTube clip you provided you can switch on subtitles. The dragon doesn't say "Thank you" in the subtitles.

Comment: @RussellKing - At some point you're going to need to accept that you're [just imagining it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia). Sorry.

Comment: @Valorum. Admittedly, the answerer hasn't helped themselves both by their original non-answer and by not providing a defintive link. But I have managed to find the sound snippet that Russell King is referring to. He's not inventing it. It's not at the point you edited to (which is why you couldn't hear it). I'll edit in the video wound to the relevant point (1:06). (I'm still not convinced it's a talking Dragon but that's another matter).

Comment: I'm retracting my downvote since this is now an answer (and one that's based upon a close attention to a canon source at that). I'm not upvoting because I dont think it's possible to definitively say that this is a talking dragon. It could be a sighing goblin or anything. If it is dragonspeak then I suspect that it was a sneaky sound editor sneaking in a very well hidden Easter egg rather than anything approved by Rowling or the scriptwriters. After all, dragons don't talk anywhere else in canon so why should this one? Nice spot, @RussellKing, anyhow.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Is that link to the same video Valorum had? If so, I watched the entire thing multiple times, and I didn't personally hear it. I'll watch it again when I get home this evening, but I'm still not yet convinced.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It's very subtle (more of a sigh) at 1:06.

Comment: @TheDarkLord I can see what you both are talking about, but those definitely aren't actual words. The first part seems to be part of the music from that scene, the second part is some kind of dragon noise.

Comment: That's not a thank you, it's two separate sounds that you can choose to interpret as sounding like a thank you, but I really don't believe it's actual speech. Just random noises that our brains interpret.